# Fourier transform with pyfftw module problem

Tags: python, fft, gaussian, pyfftw

To test the pyfftw module, I tried to compute the fourier transfom of a gaussian function knowing that the result is an other gaussian function. But there is what I get : a complet no sense result.

```
import numpy as np
import pyfftw
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import *
c=3
A=3

# Define the function to be transformed
x = np.linspace(-50, 50, 100)

"the gaussian test"
y=np.exp(-(x*x)/(2*c*c))*A

"her theoretical fourier transform, aka an other guassian"
fr=np.exp(-(x*x*c*c)/2)*(A*sqrt(2*pi)*c)

# Compute the Fourier transform using pyfftw
fourier_transform = pyfftw.interfaces.numpy_fft.fft(y)

# Plot the result

plt.plot(x,y, color='b', label="function")
plt.plot(x,fourier_transform, color='r', label="fourier f")
plt.plot(x,fr, color='g', label="theoretical ft")
plt.xlabel('x or k')
plt.ylabel('f or ~f')
plt.title("fourier transform")
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
plt.show
```

The ploting result : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njDBQ.png)

I dont know if I have to specify more arguments for the pyfftw.interfaces function or what ?

Comment: It's not nonsense at all - you got exactly what you asked for. I suggest you learn a little bit more about how FFT implementations work and what they output. A good starting point would be the [documentation](https://pyfftw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/tutorial.html#quick-and-easy-the-pyfftw-interfaces-module). If you want to ask a question along those lines, some humility would go a long way.

Answer (score 0):

`pyfftw.interfaces.numpy_fft` functions behave like their equivalents from `numpy`. You probably need to shift the zero-frequency components to the middle.

```
fourier_transform = pyfftw.interfaces.numpy_fft.fftshift(y)
```

From the [Numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.fft.html#implementation-details):

> The values in the result follow so-called “standard” order: If A = fft(a, n), then A[0] contains the zero-frequency term (the sum of the signal), which is always purely real for real inputs.
> ...
> The routine np.fft.fftshift(A) shifts transforms and their frequencies to put the zero-frequency components in the middle

[Plotting results with fftshift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vF0P.png)

Comment: The OP also ignores both the imaginary part of the result and the scaling.